# Downloading and then extracting zipped attachments using an Outlook rule

Tags: vba, outlook, zip

I have a fairly straight forward scenario where I get an email every day with a zip file attached and I would like to be able to more easily parse this information. In order to do so I just need to be able to download the attachment to a folder and then extract it.

To download the attachment I did the following

```
Public Sub SaveZip(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String

saveFolder = "c:\temp\"

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
    Set objAtt = Nothing
Next


End Sub
```

This works as expected, the .zip file gets dumped into the temp directory. I found the following code which on all accounts seems to be what I need to implement in order to extract the .zip

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oApp.NameSpace(saveFolder).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace.Items
```

I have not been able to implement this into my existing code without generating a host of errors (due to my own lack of understanding I am sure)

Any input on this would be greatly appreciated

**Final Edit**

Got it, thanks to Tim for all the help. The following will download attachments (always named the same thing) from an incoming email into c:\temp, extract them to c:\temp\unzipped, rename the file, and finally delete the .zip in c:\temp.

```
Public Sub SaveZip(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

    Const saveFolder = "C:\Temp\"
    Const fileFolder = "C:\CBH\"

    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim dName As Variant


    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

        dName = objAtt.DisplayName

        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dName

        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

        oApp.NameSpace("C:\CBH").CopyHere _
           oApp.NameSpace(saveFolder & dName).Items
        Name fileFolder & "CallsByHour.xls" As fileFolder & "CBH-" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xls"
        Kill saveFolder & dName

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim saveFolder`: remove the `As String` as noted here   http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm

Comment: Removing the identifier as well as using Variant like in the example provided produced a run time 450. I am currently looking at the example in its entirety to try and find the flaw in my logic.

Comment: You need to pass the full path to the zip archive `... oApp.NameSpace(fullZipPathGoesHere).Items`  That path should also be a Variant.

Comment: I went ahead and put my path variable (saveFolder) in there and rather than getting an error nothing happens. I am assuming this is because I need to include a file name into the path?

Comment: Yes - you need the full path including the zip filename.  Would help to update your question with the current version of your code.

Comment: I added my edit to the code, honestly very little changed as I get the feeling my understanding is considerably less than I first thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming you're coding in Outlook*, this will process the item selected in Outlook, saving the attachment to `C:\Temp` and extracting the zip contents to `C:\Temp\unzipped`

**EDIT** (untested) - added date-time based subfolder

```
Sub Tester()

    SaveZip Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

End Sub


Public Sub SaveZip(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

    Const saveFolder = "C:\Temp\"

    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim dName As Variant, unZipFolder

    If itm.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

        unZipFolder = saveFolder & "unzipped\" & " _
                      Format(Now,"yyyymmdd_hhmss")

        MkDir unZipFolder 

        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

            dName = objAtt.DisplayName

            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dName

            Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

            oApp.NameSpace(unZipFolder).CopyHere _
               oApp.NameSpace(saveFolder & dName).Items

        Next
    End If     'any attachments
End Sub
```

Comment: This works exactly as I described. It appears my mistake was in understanding the copying from and to part of the code.

Is there anything I could add to add a date stamp to the file? It occurs to me that I am going to be overwriting them each day.

Comment: That looks like it works but I was trying to get the actual file that comes out of the zip renamed in an attempt to end up with a directory of these files as opposed to a bunch of directories with one each.